# Android Phone number Calling Function in an Activity

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am developing Android Application having ContactUs Page having Phone Number. I had given the Phone number in xml file as below:

```
<TextView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
android:text="1-869-270-9099" 
android:textSize="11sp"
android:textColor="#104082"
android:textStyle="normal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/textView4" 
android:layout_x="72dp" 
android:layout_y="160dp"/>
```

I had created the `AlertDialog` and when the phone number is clicked the alert `dialog` will be shown programatically as below:

```
   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case (R.id.textView4):

        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to Call?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               //Do Calling a Number


            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
       public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case (R.id.textView4):

        showDialog(R.id.textView4);
    break;
    }

}
```

Here my issue is **to implement the "Calling a Phone Number" Function in the   `onClick` "PositiveButton" method.** Please help me how to get a DialPad with the number present in the `xml` file with the SampleCode/Links.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + findViewByid(R.id.textView4).getText());
startActivity(call);
```

Comment: You also might want to have the phone number in /res/values/strings.xml like this: `<string name="phone_num">1-869-270-9099</string>` and on your TextView `<TextView android:text="@string/phone_num" .../>`. Then just call `getResources().getString(R.string.phone_num)` whenever you need the number in your code.

This way it is easier to maintain your application and changing the phone number is easier, since you only have to change it from strings.xml and it's updated automatically everywhere where you need it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `onClick` of positive `button` just write:

```
Intent dial = new Intent();
dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+dial_number));
startActivity(dial);
```

**Note:** 
Don't forget to add this permission inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can direclty launch a intent to get the dial pad with the number mentioned in your xml file.Like this:

```
String contact=findViewById(R.id.textView4).getText().toString();
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contact));
startActivity(callIntent);
```